# Extend background to right inside column inside a container in Boostrap 3

Tags: css, background, background-image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a site using the Bootstrap 3.0 framework. I'm trying to get a kind of half border effect where there is a different background for the header and left navigation that wraps around the top and left of the page while the main content would have a darker background that extends from the left navigation infinitely to the right. I have the main content wrapped in a container and I know I'm able to extend backgrounds infinitely to the left and right by placing the content div inside of a div or other element and making that element's width 100% but how would I do this with a specific column that is already inside of a row? The main content is in a row that also has the navigation on the left. The site can be found here... http://jacobbuller.com/testsites/derekdavis/index.html

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

--- EDIT ---

I'm trying to explain this a little clearer.

Here are two images showing what I have now and what I would like...

[image: What I have made, with labels for the containers, header - which is 100% width, and col]

Basically I have a the header tag at 100% width and then inside of that I have the content wrapped in the container class to make sure it's center on the page. This way I can make the top header have a different background then the rest of the image. The rest of the page is made up of two columns wrapped in a container div. The problem I am having is making the background for the main col on the right expand 100% to the right. Here is what I would like it to look like...

[image: What I am striving for...]

I want the background of the main content col to extend 100% to the right to give the impression that it's being framed by the top header and left navigation.

Here is a short version of the header...

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    </div><!--End row -->
</div><!--End container -->
</header>
```

And the main content...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="equalHeights-sidenav"><!--equal heights JQuery so left nav is same width as main content -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar-offcanvas col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            </div><!-- End col -->

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 content">
        <div class="row"><!-- start main content row -->
            </div>
       </div>
```

There are more rows and col in the main content div but these are the two main divs surrounded it. Let me know what you think the best course of action is... if it's possible at all that is.

Comment: Your explanation is hard to understand for me.

Comment: Basically I'm wondering how to extend the background of a bootstrap column infinitely to the right on a layout but have it stop on right as soon as the column buts up with another column. It might not be possible... I hope I'm explaining this ok.

Comment: Its great if you can create screenshots of current issue and expected result.

Comment: Will do, I'll post it tonight as well as a some code to better understand what's going on, there's a lot of code in the site so I'm hesitant to post everything but I'll try and make it more clear, thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can remove the div `container` to get desired results.

Comment: Container is what's holding everything in place. VIA Boostrap 3 website, "Easily center a page's contents by wrapping its contents in a .container. Containers set width at various media query breakpoints to match our grid system." I'll take it out of the container but I feel that it will make the everything off key and make the main content extend 100% left to right instead of just the background.

Comment: After that you can adjust it